# Entry show and hide password

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I want an entry to have an icon before the placeholder, and a icon in the end of the entry, to show and hide the text in the entry, i had an entry with the show and hide icon using this tutorial:
https://www.techierathore.com/2017/09/xamarin-forms-tip-implement-show-hide-password-using-effects/

But now I want to have icons before the entry too, I can do that with this tutorial:
https://xamgirl.com/image-entry-in-xamarin-forms/

But if i add the effect of the first tutorial to the custom entry, only the  and hide/show icon shows up.

Is possible to do what i want?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use [`editText.SetCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds()`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Widget.TextView.SetCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds/p/Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable/Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable/Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable/Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable/) to add both icon.

`SetCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds` takes four parameters for start, top, end, and bottom drawable. In the first tutorial, the hide/show icon is added to the end, you can change the first parameter from 0 to your drawable.
There are three places need to modify.

For example:

```
public class ShowHidePassEffect : PlatformEffect
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        ConfigureControl();
    }

    protected override void OnDetached()
    {
    }

    private void ConfigureControl()
    {
        EditText editText = ((EditText)Control);
        editText.SetCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(Resource.Drawable.Password, 0, Resource.Drawable.ShowPass, 0);
        editText.SetOnTouchListener(new OnDrawableTouchListener());
    }
}

public class OnDrawableTouchListener : Java.Lang.Object, Android.Views.View.IOnTouchListener
{
    public bool OnTouch(Android.Views.View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        if (v is EditText && e.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
        {
            EditText editText = (EditText)v;
            if (e.RawX >= (editText.Right - editText.GetCompoundDrawables()[2].Bounds.Width()))
            {
                if (editText.TransformationMethod == null)
                {
                    editText.TransformationMethod = PasswordTransformationMethod.Instance;
                    editText.SetCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(Resource.Drawable.Password, 0, Resource.Drawable.ShowPass, 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    editText.TransformationMethod = null;
                    editText.SetCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(Resource.Drawable.Password, 0, Resource.Drawable.HidePass, 0);
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the result is:
[image]

Comment: Works, but is possible to create method or something to change the size of the icons ?

Comment: @Phill I don't think it is possible. If you need to change the size according to the DPI, you could put the Icon into different folder(`mipmap-hdpi`, `mipmap-mdpi` ...).

Comment: is this applicable on IOS?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this (solution for Xamarin iOS):

```
txt.TextWithIcon(myIcon, Colors.Black, Colors.Blue, UIReturnKeyType.Next);
```

Who calls this method

```
public static UITextField TextWithIcon(this UITextField text,
            string icon, UIColor colorBorder, UIColor colorText,
            UIReturnKeyType returnkey)
{
    text.LeftView = null; 
    var myImg = Images.LoadImageView(icon, UIViewContentMode.Center);
    myImg.Frame = new CGRect(10, 7, myImg.Frame.Width, myImg.Frame.Height);
    myImg.SizeToFit();

    var view = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, widthScreen, 70));
    view.AddSubview(myImg);

    text.LeftView = view;
    text.LeftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
    text.colorText = textColor;
    text.Layer.BorderWidth = 1f;
    text.Layer.BorderColor = colorBorder.CGColor;

    text.AttributedPlaceholder = new Foundation.NSAttributedString("placeholder", null, Colors.Black);
    text.ReturnKeyType = returnkey;
    text.SecureTextEntry = false;
    return text;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I need for android too.

Comment: Just can help you in iOS, sorry

Comment: Thanks, but first i am doing the android part.

Answer (score 1):

you can easly do something like that in xaml:

```
   <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <InputKit:AdvancedEntry
                            x:Name="Password"
                            Text="{Binding password}"
                            IsRequired="True"
                            Annotation="None"
                            AnnotationColor="#CB356B"
                            MinLength="6"
                            MaxLength="30"
                            TextColor="#000"
                            IsPassword="true"
                            FontFamily="MainFont"
                            CornerRadius="3"
                            BorderColor="#D7D6D6"
                            TextFontSize="19" 
                            StyleClass="EntryHeight"
                            />
                            <Image x:Name="show_pass_eye" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="closed_eye.png"  VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40" Margin="5,20,5,0">
                                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Tapped="ShowPassword"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Image>
                        </Grid>
```

and in c# code to make show and hide event:

```
bool eye = false;
private void ShowPassword(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!eye)
        {
            show_pass_eye.Source = "eye.png";
            Password.IsPassword = false;
            eye = true;
        }
        else 
        {
            show_pass_eye.Source = "closed_eye.png";
            Password.IsPassword = true;
            eye = false;

        }

    }
```

i hope it would help someone in future

Comment: there is no need to define the "eye" variable, if (Password.IsPassword) is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I cant reply to comment directly as per stack-overflow weird rating.
@Phil as per your comment about icon sizing below:

> Works, but is possible to create method or something to change the size of the icons ? – Phill May 29 '18 at 9:22

To change the icon size you will need to implement a ScaledBitmap. Something like this:

````
public static BitmapDrawable GetDrawable(int resID)
     {
            var context = global::Android.App.Application.Context;
            var drawable = ContextCompat.GetDrawable(context, resID);
            var bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).Bitmap;
            return new BitmapDrawable(Resources.System, Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bitmap, 60, 60, true));
     }```

//And call like this:


textCtrl.SetCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, BitMapHelper.GetDrawable(Resource.Mipmap.eye), null);
````

You can tweak the scale value to your taste.

Thanks to Billy Liu for the great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Short and simple way is below

```xml
<AbsoluteLayout >
  <Entry Keyboard="Default" IsPassword="{Binding IsPasswordShow}" Placeholder="Password" ></Entry>
  <Image Margin="2" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,.5, 25, 100" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" Source="{Binding ShowHideIcon}" >
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
      <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ShowHideTapCommand}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
  </Image>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

and C# code is in view Model:

```cs
public class LoginPasswordViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public LoginPasswordViewModel()
        {

            ShowHideTapCommand = new Command(() =>
            {
                IsPasswordShow = !IsPasswordShow;
            });
        }

        private bool _isPasswordShow;
        public bool IsPasswordShow
        {
            get { return _isPasswordShow; }
            set
            {
                _isPasswordShow = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                OnPropertyChanged("ShowHideIcon");
            }
        }

        public string ShowHideIcon
        {
            get
            {
                return IsPasswordShow ? "show.png" : "hide.png";
            }
        }

        public ICommand LoginCommand { get; }
        public ICommand ShowHideTapCommand { get; }
    }
```