# custom entry box with icon for xamarin form (android,ios)

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image: preview image that shows the desired design showing an entry with a placeholder and an icon]

Entry box should be rounded with an icon to the left or right in it. I'm using [the code presented here](http://www.xamarinbuddy.com/2017/12/custom-curved-corners-entry.html) to create this custom entry.

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50512908/entry-show-and-hide-password/

Comment: I use a simple way of layouting `Image` next to an `Entry`. I have posted my answer below. Will using a simple layout for this not solve your requirement? I'm a bit confused if your requirement is similar to mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Remove the rectangular border of `Entry`**

Used CustomRender to achieve this.

*Forms*

```
public class NoUnderlineEntry : Entry
{
    public NoUnderlineEntry()
    {
    }
}
```

*Android*
Set `Background` to `null`

```
public class NoUnderLineEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        this.Control.Background = null;
    }
}
```

*iOS*

Set `BorderStyle` to `None`

```
public class NoUnderlineEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        this.Control.BorderStyle = UIKit.UITextBorderStyle.None;
    }
}
```

**2. Placing `Image` next to `Entry`**

Adding Image and Entry to the same Grid in two columns.

**3. Adding Rounded border to the `Entry` and `Image`**

Add them inside a Frame with CornerRadius.

*XAML*

```
<StackLayout>
        <Frame
            Padding="10, 5, 10, 5"
            HasShadow="False"
            BorderColor="Gray"
            CornerRadius="30">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <local:NoUnderlineEntry/>
                <Image Source="icon.png" Grid.Column="1" WidthRequest="50" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
            </Grid>
        </Frame>
    </StackLayout>
```

UI result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Please note:** I won't present a copy-and-paste-able answer, but rather an outline on how to add the images. You'll have to integrate the code in your solution by yourself.

#### On iOS

There already is an answered question on how to achieve this with Swift on iOS, [you can find it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27903500/swift-add-icon-image-in-uitextfield).

Basically what to do is to set the right view (or left view respectively) on the `UITextField` from your custom renderer (in `OnElementChanged`).

```cs
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    var imageView = new UIImageView(new CGRect(0, 0, 20, 20));
    var image = UIImage.FromFile("ic_location.png");
    imageView.Image = image;
    this.Control.RightView = imageView;
    this.Control.RightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
}
```

This sets the view in the right of the `UITextField` to a `UIImageView`. If you wanted to show the icon **before** the text instead, you'd have to set `LeftView` and `LeftViewMode` instead. [This is how it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZc5y.png) (I intentionally did not inline the image, because it rendered the answer less redable.)

Of course the file `ic_location.png` has to be in your platform projects resources.

You may need some fine tuning, but basically that's it.

#### On Android

The `TextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds`

> Sets the Drawables (if any) to appear to the left of, above, to the right of, and below the text. Use `null` if you do not want a Drawable there. The Drawables' bounds will be set to their intrinsic bounds. ([source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)))

By loading the icon from the resource and setting it with `SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` (uppercase now, since we're now on C#) you can display the `Entry` with the icon:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    this.Control.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, this.GetIcon(), null);
    this.Control.CompoundDrawablePadding = 25;
}

private Drawable GetIcon()
{
    int resID = Resources.GetIdentifier("ic_location", "drawable", this.Context.PackageName);
    var drawable = ContextCompat.GetDrawable(this.Context, resID);
    var bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).Bitmap;

    return new BitmapDrawable(Resources, Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bitmap, 20, 20, true));
}
```

[This is how the Android version looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFL5O.png)

For showing the icon on left left, pass the drawable to the first parameter instead of the third.