# Xamarin Show/Hide Password

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a registration form in Xamarin Forms. And I'm trying to enable the user to see the text input in Password Entry.

I'm sorry for this question, but I am new to Xamarin.

I saw this solution : [Entry show and hide password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50512908/entry-show-and-hide-password)

But i don't know where to put the code.

I added it to the MainActivity.cs but it does not work when i debug it using my android Phone.

Can someone help me to implement this code to my RegisterPage.

this is my code for Entry Password.

```
<Entry Margin="20,0,20,0" 
       HeightRequest="50" IsPassword="true"
       Placeholder="Password"
       x:Name="txtPassword"
       Text="{Binding passWord}">
</Entry>

<Entry Margin="20,0,20,0" 
       HeightRequest="50" IsPassword="true"
       Placeholder="Confirm Password"
       x:Name="txtConfPassword"
       Text="{Binding passWord}">
</Entry>
```

Comment: the code you linked to is an Effect.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/introduction

Comment: have a look at this 

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-tip-implement-show-hide-password-using-effects/

Comment: @ShubhamTyagi Thank you sir.

Comment: @LevesqueXylia If have solved this, remember to share your solution in answer. Then other prople who meet the same problem will know it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way to achieve that can custom a View with `Entry` and `ImageButton` in Xamarin Forms, then you will not need to use custom Effects in each platform.

For example, create a **SecurityEntry** ContentView.

**Xaml** code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XamarinForms20.SecurityEntry">
  <ContentView.Content>
      <RelativeLayout Margin="5">
            <Entry x:Name="MyEntry"
                   Text="123456789" 
                   MaxLength="18"
                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=X, Constant=0}"
                   RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Y, Constant=0}"
                   RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.9}"
                   RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant= 50}" />

            <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                         Source="eyeon.png" Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked"
                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Constant=-50}"
                   RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Y, Constant = 0}"
                   RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.10}"
                   RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.10}" />

        </RelativeLayout>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

**.cs** code:

```
public partial class SecurityEntry : ContentView
{
    public SecurityEntry()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ImageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var imageButton = sender as ImageButton;
        if(MyEntry.IsPassword)
        {
            imageButton.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("eyeon.png");
            MyEntry.IsPassword = false;
        }
        else
        {
            imageButton.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("eyeoff.png");
            MyEntry.IsPassword = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Then we can use it in Xaml of Some **ContentPage.Xaml**:

```
<local:SecurityEntry WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="50"/>
```

Now we can see the effect as follows:

[image]

If need to get the Value of `Entry`, we bind model for it. Then we can get the value by **MVVM**.

For example, create a sample Model data in ContentPage:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public string TextValue { set; get; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TextValue = "I come from model";
        BindingContext = this;
    }
 }
```

Then in **SecurityEntry.Xaml** modify as follow:

```
 ...
 <Entry x:Name="MyEntry"
        Text="{Binding TextValue}" 
 ...
```

The effect will show:

[image]

Comment: Wow. Thank you sir. Easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can show/hide the entry by changing the bool value of IsPassword of your entry.
txtConfPassword.IsPassword = true or false according to your requirement in the Registration page.

Comment: Yes, maybe that could be a possible solution, but my goal is to have an Icon inside the Entry, and the Icon of the Show password is also inside the Entry. that is why I am trying to implement the link I have attached on my question.

Comment: You can use an absolute layout to put the icon inside the entry